# WMD editor - how to create hyperlink on an image?

Tags: wmd

Using the [WMD markdown edito](http://wmd-editor.com/)r, how can I create a hyperlink on an image ?

I saw some people managed to do this, but how?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like so:

```
[![Alt Text Goes Here][1]][2]

  [1]: http://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/articles/ca/86-random/figs/gif150/86random-f1.1.gif
  [2]: http://www.google.com/search?q=random+image
```

Turns out like this:

[image: Alt Text Goes Here]